# SharePoint Licensing - Migration from Enterprise to Standard farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-migration

Company A sold subsidiary company B to company C. Company A has SharePoint 2010 enterprise version with all enterprise features turned off. Company B has some site collections in company A SharePoint farm which needs to be migrated to company C.

**Question:**

Company C wants to go for standard version of SharePoint. Is there going to be any issues when we restore of site collections in standard version of SharePoint farm?
Please note we are not restoring any databases. We are building a new farm in Company C and just restoring site collections of company B.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-content migration from Enterprise to Standard is unsupported by Microsoft. So if you used a Content Migration tool, you could do it that way. But you would not be able to do a `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite`, or `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb`, and of course, though you're not performing it, a content database restore.